# Can't run python libraries due to python 2/3 issues

Tags: python

I am running on a fresh install of OpenSUSE 13.2 tumbleweed which comes with python2.7 and python3.4. I am continually having problems running any python based libs in getting the following error `ImportError: No module named site`. All the answers for this issue deal with setting the PYTHONPATH and/or PYTHONHOME env vars to some path, but I have tried every path combination I can think of and nothing works.  An ideas?

The libraries I am having problems with are youtube-dl and flexget.

Comment: A couple of things to try. `python -v`,  will print a message everytime a module'is loaded/unloaded.  `python -S` (run without site module).

Answer (score 2):

1. This is your distro's job, to get library management right - even for things like python which seem to go out of their way to make it difficult.
2. Run python 2 programs with `#!/usr/bin/python2` and python 3 programs with `#!/usr/bin/python3`.  Or by calling them as `python2 script` or `python3 script`.  Don't use `#!/usr/bin/env python`, that was moronically bad advice even before there were two pythons.
3. Use the distro's packaged versions of python libraries whenever possible.  Even if you have to wait a whole week for version 1.2.0.0.0.0.3 to be packaged while you're stuck on ancient 1.2.0.0.0.0.2.  Or months.  It's extremeley rare that an upgraded library is worth taking the risk of messing up your system.  Going without, or "use another lib" is almost always a better answer than "mess up my system by manually installing this lib"
4. If you must manually install a library, **adapt the instructions to suit your system**.  The instructions may (mostly) work on the developer's own system, but they'll make an enormous number of assumptions about how things are set up - and most of them will probably be wrong for your system.
   This means thoroughly reading the distro's relevant documentation and notes and understanding your system's python environment and how it works.
5. Not adapting the instructions to suit your system can mess up your python environment even if your distro did everything right as far as python lib management goes.  This is a sadly common outcome for python (and ruby) in ways that are not common for any other programming or scripting language.  There is a LOT of bad advice that essentially tells you to ignore the distro or operating system and treat it as an obstacle to be worked around (rather than a tool to be used and worked with) out there in the python world.